# Jetty web.xml 503

Tags: java, xml, jersey, jetty, jersey-2.0

So I'm trying to set up Jetty for a school project, using Jersey on the server side and Gradle to build and run it. I have my web.xml and a test that I'm trying to hit with curl. Here's what I got:

`web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Project</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>../index.html</welcome-file> 
    </welcome-file-list>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>Project</param-name>
         <param-value>main.java.package</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Reservations</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

`Web.java`

```
package main.java.package;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
Import javax.ws.rx.GET;
@Path("api/")
public class Web {

    @GET
    @Path("test/")
    public String test() {
        return "it works!";
    }

}
```

When I curl `http://localhost:8080/project/api/test` I just get a 503. So I'm assuming it's something with my `web.xml` but I just can't figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your servlet mapping is incorrect - there is no servlet declared with the name `Reservations` anywhere.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <!-- <servlet-name>Reservations</servlet-name> -->
    <servlet-name>Project</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then pls read the [user-guide for jaxrs resources](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#jaxrs-resources)

The resource path would match `./project/api/api/test` and not `./project/api/test`.

So here are some fixes:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Project</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern> <!-- ApplicationPath -->
</servlet-mapping>
```

```java
@Path("/test") // resource path 
public class Test { // changed from class Web, 'cause resource is ./test

    @GET // [GET] ./project/api/test
    // @Path("test/") - path is already given by class path
    public String test() {
        return "it works!"; 
    }

    @GET // [GET] ./project/api/test/foo
    @Path("/foo")
    public String testFoo() {
        return "it works for foo!";
    }

}
```

Hope this was helpfull somehow:)

Answer (score 1):

Add `@javax.ws.rs.GET` to your `test()` method.

Comment: Ah, I did forget that, but it's still giving me a 503