# Serving Static Content Jetty Jersey Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jersey, jetty, jersey-2.0

So I'm trying to get my Jetty/Jersey/Gradle setup to serve up index.html which is in `src/main/webapp/static/` when at the default url. I have `/api` for my java server, so I figured showing static content would be somewhat easy but I'm running into problems. Here is what I have in my `web.xml`

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Webapp Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>main/webapp/static</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.servlet.filter.staticContentRegex</param-name>
      <param-value>/.*html</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter> 
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Webapp Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
  </filter-mapping>
```

Am I missing something or doing something wrong? When I do `gradle jettyRun` I get

```
The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
failed Webapp Filter: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
Failed startup of context org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.internal.JettyPluginWebAppContext@48e8a298{/Project,/User/Project/src/main/webapp}
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
```

so it makes me think that it's looking at the right place but maybe it's just not finding the correct thing? Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it

Comment: Could you pls give some feedback?!?

Answer (score 1):

The exception means:
`com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.` noticed you, that jersey can't find service classes.

Your init-param `jersey.config.server.provider.packages` isnt set correct and additionally at the wrong place. Thats the place where you want to add resource CLASSES and after that, jersey wants to find some @Path annotations aka resource classes in there.
As i said, its at the wrong place - its not part of an filter, its part of the `ServletContainer` servlet config. Alternatively you could leave this out and declare packages in your `ResourceConfig` or `Application` implementation.

pls read: [deployment guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#deployment)

Summary:

```
<filter>...</filter>
```

is where you can place filters and

```
<servlet>...</servlet>
```

(i can't find in your part of web.xml) is where you should insert `ServletContainer` to.

Cause I've answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837852/jetty-web-xml-503) to you yesterday, i really advice you to read the manuals and try some sample projects, like:

[gradle & tomcat](https://github.com/jasonray/jersey-starterkit/wiki/Create-a-%22Hello-World%22-jersey-project)
[jersey examples](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/)

You will also find some web.xml there.

Comment: I ended up doing it a different way, with having a `<welcome-file>` and then using AngularJS to reroute and show other pages.